# Angular 2 reactive Forms - I like Models

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

### Usecase

Lets imagine you built a form where a user can choose stuff to become cooked tomorrow. The user has created a list of favorit food. So - the user sees a screen where he can either enter whatever food he wants, but also could select one of the previous defined "favorit foods".

So - the server is questioned for the list of favorit foods which is displayed in the form, but also the form displayes an empty row where the user could enter whatever he likes to eat.

There is one checkbox in front of each line where the user can select the dishes which have to be cooked.

### Code

Inside the TypeScript of the Component I really want to work with a `DishModel` containing one entered/selected dish. Since the user may select multiple dishes, the whole model is an array of `DishModel`s.

At one point I have translated the JSON response from the server with all my favorit dishes to an array of `DishModel`s to get them displayed together  with an "empty" `DishModel`.

To do this, I loop through my `DishModel`s and creat an Array-Group with my `FormBuilder`. At that point I assign the models properties to Form Controls.
When the form is then submitted, I'd like to continue working with my model so I have to get back all the form values in my `DishModel` array. And this feels bad...

To ease the converting back the form-array to my Model I created a constructor in my Model to deal with that. But now this means that I really need to take care to neither change the Model private property names nor the Form Control names without changing the other as well... This is not a good design. In this point, the "model way of form" felt better where I didn't needed to convert a model to a array to get it in a form and vice versa to process it back.

Is this the way how to do it or is there  any possible way to keep reactive forms but use a Model throughout the whole application?

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/JZIjXH9CagJNHLxK64fG?p=preview